# Join of two databases

Tags: java, join

This is the most basic code to join two tables in a database. For tables it uses a simple list. Solved this using brute force, sorting and using hashtable.

```
final class SportsMan {

    private final String name;
    private final int rank;
    private final String sport;

    public SportsMan (String name, int rank, String sport)  {
        this.name = name;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.sport = sport;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public String getSport() {
        return sport;
    }
}


final class Sport {

    private final String sport;
    private final int numberOfPlayers;

    public Sport(String sport, int numberOfPlayers) {
        this.sport = sport;
        this.numberOfPlayers = numberOfPlayers;
    }

    public String getSport()  {
        return sport;
    }

    public int getNumberOfPlayers() {
        return numberOfPlayers;
    }
}


final class Result {

    private final String name;
    private final int rank;
    private final String sport;
    private final int numberOfPlayers;

    public Result (String name, int rank, String sport, int numberOfPlayers) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.sport = sport;
        this.numberOfPlayers = numberOfPlayers;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public String getSport() {
        return sport;
    }

    public int getNumberOfPlayers() {
        return numberOfPlayers;
    }

}

public final class Joins {

    private Joins () {}

    public static List<Result> innerJoinBruteForce(List<SportsMan> sportsMen, List<Sport> sportList) {
        final List<Result> resultSet = new ArrayList<Result>();
        for (SportsMan sportsMan : sportsMen) {
            for (Sport sport : sportList) {
                if (sportsMan.getSport().equals(sport.getSport())) {
                    resultSet.add(new Result(sportsMan.getName(), sportsMan.getRank(), sport.getSport(), sport.getNumberOfPlayers()));
                }
            }
        }
        return resultSet;
    }


    public class SportsMenComparator implements Comparator<SportsMan> {
        @Override
        public int compare(SportsMan s1, SportsMan s2) {
            return s1.getSport().compareTo(s2.getSport());
        }
     }

    public class SportComparator implements Comparator<Sport> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Sport sport1, Sport sport2) {
            return sport1.getSport().compareTo(sport2.getSport());
        }
    }

    public static List<Result> innerJoinSort(List<SportsMan> sportsMansList, List<Sport> sportList) {
        List<Result> result = new ArrayList<Result>();

        Collections.sort(sportsMansList, new Joins().new SportsMenComparator());
        Collections.sort(sportList, new Joins().new SportComparator());

        int sportsManCtr = 0;
        int sportsCtr = 0; 

        while (sportsManCtr < sportsMansList.size() && sportsCtr < sportList.size()) {
            SportsMan sportsMan =  sportsMansList.get(sportsManCtr); 
            Sport sport = sportList.get(sportsCtr);
            if (sportsMan.getSport().compareTo(sport.getSport()) > 0) {
                sportsCtr++;
            } else if (sportsMan.getSport().compareTo(sport.getSport()) < 0) {
                sportsManCtr++;
            } else {
                result.add(new Result(sportsMan.getName(), sportsMan.getRank(), sport.getSport(), sport.getNumberOfPlayers()));
                sportsManCtr++;
                sportsCtr++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }


    public static  List<Result> innerJoinHash(List<SportsMan> sportsManList, List<Sport> sportList) {
        List<Result> result = null;

        Map hashMap;
        if (sportsManList.size() < sportList.size()) {
            hashMap = new HashMap();
            for (SportsMan sportsman :  sportsManList) {
                hashMap.put(sportsman.getSport(), sportsman);
            }
            for (Sport sport : sportList) {
                if (hashMap.containsKey(sport.getSport())) {
                    SportsMan sportsMan = (SportsMan) hashMap.get(sport.getSport());
                    result.add(new Result(sportsMan.getName(), sportsMan.getRank(), sportsMan.getSport(), sportsMan.getRank()));
                }
            }

        } else {
            hashMap = new HashMap();
            for (Sport sport :  sportList) {
                hashMap.put(sport.getSport(), sport);
            }
            for (SportsMan sportsMan : sportsManList) {
                if (hashMap.containsKey(sportsMan.getSport())) {
                    Sport sport = (Sport) hashMap.get(sportsMan.getSport());
                    result.add(new Result(sportsMan.getName(), sportsMan.getRank(), sportsMan.getSport(), sportsMan.getRank()));
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

       List<SportsMan> sportsMenList = new ArrayList<SportsMan>();
       sportsMenList.add(new SportsMan("sachin", 1, "cricket"));
       sportsMenList.add(new SportsMan("nadal", 1, "tennis"));
       sportsMenList.add(new SportsMan("tiger", 1, "golf"));
       sportsMenList.add(new SportsMan("pele", 1, "soccer"));


       List<Sport> sportList = new ArrayList<Sport>();
       sportList.add(new Sport("cricket", 11));
       sportList.add(new Sport("tennis", 2));
       sportList.add(new Sport("golf", 1));


       List<Result> resultSet1 = innerJoinBruteForce(sportsMenList, sportList);
       for (Result result : resultSet1) {
           System.out.print(result.getSport() + " : ");
       }


       List<Result> resultSet2 = innerJoinSort(sportsMenList, sportList);
       for (Result result : resultSet2) {
           System.out.print(result.getSport() + " : ");
       }

       List<Result> resultSet3 = innerJoinSort(sportsMenList, sportList);
       for (Result result : resultSet3) {
           System.out.print(result.getSport() + " : ");
       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you aren't using [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html):

```
Map hashMap; // no generics :o
Map<String, Object> hashMap; // generics :D
```

---

The variable `result` can only be `null` in the function `innerJoinHash()`:

```
result.add(new Result(sportsMan.getName(), sportsMan.getRank(), sportsMan.getSport(), sportsMan.getRank()));
```

This is because you are initializing `result` to `null`:

```
List<Result> result = null;
```

You should initiate the list right away:

```
List<Result> result = new ArrayList<Result>();
```

---

The value of the local variable `sport` is not used, and therefore can be removed:

```
Sport sport = (Sport) hashMap.get(sportsMan.getSport());
```